# Is there any way to customize the css transition?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

As far as I understand, if I'm trying to modify the style of an element which has the transition property, the modification will be executed in a gradual way. So is there any way to listen the change of the style, prevent the immediate modification and replace it with a custom animation?

Comment: You can use the [transition-timing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function) to set how intermediate values are calculated for CSS properties being affected by a transition effect. I'm not entirely sure if this is what you were asking though.

Answer (score 0):

that is transion If you want change the color using css transition
[click more details](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/)

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Whilst correct, this does not answer the question?

Comment: what do you want there?